# separate mappingResources from spring hibernate LocalSessionFactoryBean

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

Ok, I have this spring hibernate xml configuration.

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>com/abc/def/a.xml</value>
            <value>com/abc/def/b.xml</value>
            <value>com/abc/def/c.xml</value>
            <!-- 
            And so on, about 50 xml for example
            How can I separate list value above into 5 file for example? 
            ex I have h1.xml (or h1.txt) that contain 
            <value>com/abc/def/a.xml</value>
            <value>com/abc/def/b.xml</value>
            I have h2.xml (or h2.txt) that contain 
            <value>com/abc/def/c.xml</value>
            <value>com/abc/def/d.xml</value>
            so the mappingResources just read from the files (more than 1) than contain all mapping objects
            -->
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.OSCacheProvider</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop> 
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I have commented the question in the xml configuration above.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can just use

```
    <property name="mappingLocations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:com/abc/def/*.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
```

Comment: It's work! I'm use property mappingLocations and then classpath:com/abc/def/**/*.hbm.xml.  Thanks!